Kullback-Leibler divergence as a sum over “$T$” with product of multivariate Gaussians?
Imagine we have two multivariate Gaussian random variables and both of them can be written as the product of “$T$” individual probability density functions.
Can we write the Kullback-Leibler divergence as a sum over “$T$”? If this is possible, could you show it for the case $T=2$?
Most of the KL divergence is purely linear, so my gut tells me absolutely. But the ratio of log determinant terms of the covariance is stumping me. For a product of Gaussians we will have a sum of inverse covariance matrices, and we cannot simply (linearly) distribute the determinant across a sum without things getting messy fast. What am I missing?

Never mind!
My original approach was too complicated.
Don't substitute into the KL form for generic G.R.V.s too early!
This simply follows from the linearity of expectation and the properties of logarithms as follows for the case of $T=2$ with $X = (x_1 \cdot x_2)$ and $Y = (y_1 \cdot y_2)$:
$$\begin{aligned} \text{KL}(X || Y) &= \mathbb{E}_X [\log(X) - \log(Y)]\\
&= \mathbb{E}_X [\log(x_1 \cdot x_2) - \log(y_1 \cdot y_2) ]\\ &= \mathbb{E}_X [ \log(x_1) + \log (x_2) - \log(y_1) - \log( y_2)] \\ &= \mathbb{E}_{x_1} [ \log(x_1) - \log(y_1)] + \mathbb{E}_{x_2} [ \log (x_2) - \log( y_2)] \\ &= \text{KL} (x_1 || y_1) + \text{KL} (x_2 || y_2)\end{aligned} $$
And then the case for $T=N$ is very easy to generalize from here.
